# Logout em PHP com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, login

Estou com um problema no logout do meu sistema, ele até que está fazendo logout corretamente e destruindo as sessões, mas se o usuário clicar no botão de voltar do navegador ele volta a página anterior do sistema onde é exibido todos os dados novamente. O código está assim:

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy(); //destroi a sessao
    redirect('/'); // redireciona para a raiz do sistema(pagina de login)
}
```

Mesmo destruindo a sessão, ele consegue acessar a página anterior do sistema, as verificações de sessão dentro do programa estão corretas, pois se ele clicar em um link e for pra outro módulo ele será expulso do sistema.

Alguém pode me ajudar?? Obrigado :)

Comment: Creio que uma boa prática, é analisar as sessions antes de renderizar o conteúdo. Caso a sessão esteja vazia, redireciona para o login.

Answer (score 3):

Tem um tempo que não mexo com Codeigniter, mas a solução abaixo funcionará com qualquer outro framework (ou até mesmo no PHP puro).

Considerando que você destruiu a sessão, para garantir que a sessão anterior não seja acessada (seja por algum bug do framework ou qualquer outro erro), você pode simplesmente regenerar o id, para que a referência anterior seja perdida.

Nesse caso, faça assim:

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    $this->session->regenerate_id();

    redirect('/');
}
```

## Atualização

Foi informado que `regenerate_id` não funcionou. Então, você pode usar `$this->session->sess_update()`.

Comment: Não funcionou, o Codeigniter não tem a função regenerate_id()

Comment: Se a atualização não funcionar, eu removo o post.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas

```html
 public function sair(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    
    redirect('view aonde quer voltar');
  }
```